# Test execution of python scripts from another python script

Tags: python

I have a set of log generating python scripts. I have to write testing python script to check whether all the log generating python scripts are executed without any errors and if there are any errors the python script should just display the filename without printing the traceback errors. I am working on windows.

1. Need traceback messages to be not displayed. (sys.tracebacklimit = 0 doesn't seem to work)
2. Whenever a file is failing , an exception is being raised and followed by several exceptions saying file not found errors which are in the same directory. This happens only when any of the files fail. When they all pass its working as expected.

```
for file in file_list:
        try:
            cmd = 'python {file}'
            os.system(cmd)
        except:
            print(f'{file} passed')
        else:
            print(f'{file} failed')
```

Comment: #1. Is there a reason you aren't importing your .pys and running them inside the same console?     
#2. If the log generating scripts don't use the python logging function, you could use it across them all (https://zetcode.com/python/logging/)

Comment: @Amiga500 #1 Those .pys are not functions can we run them by just importing I am fairly new to python. What I was trying to do is there are some python scripts which parse some log files and produce a text file. #2 I dont think I need python logging support. I need to just parse some log files and get meaningful data printed.

Answer (score 0):

This is addressing the reply to #1

Yep, if you import the .py then you can run them. Might need a little tweak, but its straightforward.

[May or may not need this step] Add the .py folder area to the system path

```
sys.path.append('C:\\abc\\efg\\')  #Obviously sub in your actual path
```

Then in your primary script, import as normal (say module1.py)

```
import module1  #omitting the .py off the end

try:
    module1.main()   #Call as per this
    print("module1 passed")
except:
    print("module1 failed")
```

Within each subscript, you may need to edit as below

```
#Legacy
Existing functions here

# -----------------------------------
def main()
    #Put anything you currently have in __main__ here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Doing this means that behaviour is identical if called within your IDE and if called externally